# VSCode Doctrine DQL Support

Tags: symfony, visual-studio-code, doctrine, doctrine-query

I recently switch to vsCode, and I'm facing to a little problem.
PHP Intelephense works well for php and symfony completion, but when I wrote DQL / Query Builder I didn't have autocomplete of the field of entity :

```
$qb
    ->select('u.id, u.field1, u.field2, rel.field1')
    ->leftJoin('u.relation', 'rel')
    ->where('rel.fieldOnRelation = :condition')
    ->setParameter('condition', 'xxx')
;
```

`u.*` didn't complete, and on leftJoin, I didn't have the field of the `u` entity to choose, I need to type it manually.

I was on PhpStorm previously and the autocomplete works on dql.

Answer (score 0):

This VSX extension claims to do just that: https://open-vsx.org/extension/tmrdh/symfony-helper

I tried it and it's not nearly on PhpStorm's level but AFAIK it's the best option available.

Be aware that the GitHub repo returns a 404 and the author is not verified which is not very reassuring.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Will try, but it's seems to be not a good solution in theses conditions :)